# Syntax for Getting Ouput Variable in Structured Text

Tags: plc, st

I'm trying to use a library defined function (CCaux for Cross Control Products) with the following interface:

```
FUNCTION Lightsensor_GetIlluminance : eErr (* return error status. 0 ERR_SUCCESS, otherwise error code.*)
VAR_OUTPUT
    value: UINT;(*Illuminace value (Lux)*)
END_VAR
```

I can't seem to find the correct syntax for getting the "value" from the output variable. Here is what I have in my program:

```
VAR
    illumen : UINT;
END_VAR
```

Where I want `illumen` to be set to the output variable of `Lightsensor_GetIlluminace`. The following doesn't work since it sets the variable to the `eErr`:

```
illumen := CCAux.Lightsensor_GetIlluminance();
```

And:

```
illumen := CCAux.Lightsensor_GetIlluminance.value;
```

Doesn't work because I get the error `'value' is no input of 'Lightsensor_GetIlluminance'`

And:

```
illumen := CCAux.Lightsensor_GetIlluminance(value := illumen);
```

fails because `Lightsensor_GetIlluminance take exactly '0' inputs`

I am using CoDeSys for context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the syntax for functions with additional outputs:

```
<function> (<function output variable1> => <output variable 1>, <function output variable n> => <output variable n>)
```

The following code should return the "Illuminace value":

```
 CCAux.Lightsensor_GetIlluminance(value => illumen);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have output variable like this

```
FUNCTION Lightsensor_GetIlluminance : eErr 
VAR_OUTPUT
    value: UINT;
END_VAR
```

Then in the code you may uget your additional varaible like this.

```
eErr := Lightsensor_GetIlluminance(value => illumen);
```

Or if you create `FUNCTION_BLOCK` then in addition to method above you can use something like this.

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK Lightsensor_GetIlluminance 
VAR_OUTPUT
    value: UINT;
    error : eErr;
END_VAR
```

And in the code

```
Lightsensor_GetIlluminance();
IF NOT Lightsensor_GetIlluminance.error THEN
    illumen := Lightsensor_GetIlluminance.value;
END_IF;
```

So you may access varaible throu `.` but you have to call FB upfront.